# Error causes password change while updating new data in Yii

Tags: database, yii, passwords

While I'm trying to update the AID field in database with this function:

```
static function aidInsert()
{
    $model = Users::model()->findAll();
    foreach($model as $m)
    {
        $code = alphabeticCode();
        $aidk = Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('aid'=>$code));
        if(!empty($aidk))
        {
            $code = alphabeticCode();
        }
        $m->aid = $code;
        $m->save();
    }
}
```

(alphabeticCode Method is just a method used to generate random strings.)

the whole user's password stored in password field is completely changed into some piece of md5 hash, right after this function completed.

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: Maybe your model is having beforeSave function which modifies the password. Try using $m->update()

Comment: Thank you so much Parry. It's exactly as you said.
Password is modified due to this line in beforeSave function:
$this->password = md5(Yii::app()->params['secretKey'].md5($this->password));

In some other situations, I'm afraid that I need to use something like $md->save(). What should I do in order to fix it throughly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `save()` saves every attribute by default - but you can specify which attributes to save:

```
$m->save(true, array('aid'));
// true to use validation, the array to specify which attributes to save
```

Comment: So in the case of update, should I use your suggestion or $m->update(array('aid'))?